# Collect Instagram Followers

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Good evening everyone. I'm supposed to teach a data processing course for high school students. The course is based on data extracted from Instagram. There are several tools in `python`, `R` etc. that I could use to extract data from Instagram. But I'd like the students to do that, and the course is too short to introduce languages like these I mentioned. Furthermore, students come from different fields and may not have sufficient technical knowledge to follow a programming course. A (free) web collector of Instragram followers where it is possible to search for the user and then click on "download" to scrape their followers (if any) might be a good solution for these students. Do you know similar tools?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it weird that a high school course is promoting one privately owned social media platform?   If students just need a downloaded list to work with, why force students to access Instagram?  Just supply them a list to manipulate and skip the in class brand promotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure we are the correct platform for this question but you have [this chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-list-of-followers/hcdbfckhdcpepllecbkaaojfgipnpbpb?hl=en-US) extension and detailed explanation here [How to Export Instagram Followers to Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxC-XIfD5es)

Video description has all the steps:

"1.    You’ll need to have Google Chrome installed, just follow the instructions on their website.
With Chrome installed, either search for Helper Tools for Instagram or go to this link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/de....
Then click Add to Chrome.

2. Go to the Instagram page you wish to export a list of followers and click the new icon in the top-right to open the Helper Tools.
3. In this case we want just the followers, so change the box from All to Followers and then click Get List of Users.
4. Make sure you have ample time to generate the list as it can take hours if there are many followers. "

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape/collect any instagram followers of any account in this web. Just create account and try for free. https://phantombuster.com/automations/instagram/7175/instagram-follower-collector